# Equalities involving power of natural numbers

Tags: inequality, exponentiation, natural-numbers

If I have $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\alpha>0$ is the following true?
$$(2N)^\alpha-(2N+2)^{\alpha}<0$$
and
$$-(2N+1)^\alpha+(2N+3)^{\alpha}>0$$
I think yes since $2N<2N+2$ and $2N+3>2N+1$.

Comment: Yes, this follows from the fact that $x^\alpha$ is an increasing function for $x\ge0$ when $\alpha$ is positive.

Comment: Thanks a lot for confirming my idea!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes those are true this because for $x\ge 0$ , $x^\alpha$ for any constant  $\alpha>0$ is a monotonically increasing function of $x$ which means that $a>b\implies a^{\alpha}>b^{\alpha}$ for all $a,b\ge 0$.